# how do you erase polygons that don't have a line intersection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, intersection

I am trying to erase any polygons that do not have a line intersection through them and am unsure of what tool to use
using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: Hi Claire, welcome to GIS.SE. Please indicate with the appropriate tag or in your question what software you're using to attempt this.

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.1

Answer (score 3):

To remove polygons that don't have an intersection with lines:

Open ArcMap and add the polygons and lines to the table of contents.

Locate the Select by Locations dialog and select the ones that do intersect.

[image: Select by location]

Switch the selection by going to the selection in the table of contents

[image: Selection tab]

Right click on the layer name and select 'switch selection'.

Start editing and press delete:

[image: Edit Delete]

Don't forget to save edits.